# Create a widget that displays an activity from any app

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts, home-screen, app-widgets, customization

I want to create a widget that will display an activity from another app (not something I built). For example, I want to have a widget that shows the stopwatch activity from the clock app.

I am not looking to do this as part of an application I am building, but as a customisation. I tried KWGT, but was unable to find how to do it. Is there any way to do this using KWGT, or similar apps. If there are other alternates, please tell me.

I am on Android 10, if it is relevant.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I assume you meant creating a home screen widget from any app as an end-user? Note that app development is off-topic since Android Enthusiasts focuses on end-users or power-users (but not necessarily developers) solving their issues.

Comment: @Andrew T Yes. As I mentioned, I am not looking to build any app. I am an end user, just wanting to costomize the home screen. I am looking for a KGWT like solution, which I suppose is on-topic. If not, redirect me, please.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, and yes, it's on-topic here.